# allow 's regex in a javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript to allow just letters, numbers, space, _, - in one input:

```
var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
if (!re.test(form.titulo.value)) {
    alert("Error: Input contains invalid characters!");
    form.titulo.focus();
    return false;
}
```

the problem is, I want to allow ' too. So I can type something like: Ana's house, don't... I try to just add ' in the regex, but it didn't work:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-']+)$/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the hyphen in a character class indicates a range, unless it is at the end (where it clearly can't be a range) or is escaped. You can also remove capturing group as it is not required in your case.

1. Escape `-`

   ```
   /^[a-zA-Z0-9 _\-']+$/
   ```
2. Move `-` at the beginning or end of the class

   ```
   /^[a-zA-Z0-9 _'-]+$/
   ```

**Demo**

```css
input {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 _\-']+" />
```

Comment: @RickJoe I've added Live Demo, you can try in it

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9 _'-]+)$/
```

When `-` is not the first or last character in the brackets, it means you're selecting a range of characters, like when you do `a-z` or `0-9`. When you wrote `_-'` it meant all the characters between `_` and `'`.

You can also escape the `-` to keep it from having special meaning.

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9 _\-']+)$/
```

BTW, you can use `\w` as an abbreviation for `a-zA-Z0-9_`, so your regexp can be simplified to:

```
/^[\w \-']+$/
```

Comment: In the simplified regex, you missed space

Comment: Thx, didn't notice that